# Don't issue a token in Identity Server 4 when a user is set to inactive

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

We've recently implemented the ability to disable users in our application with an "Active" boolean field in the `Identity.AspNetUsers` table. Logging in to the back office system (an Angular application) is easily handled with an implicit flow -- simply check the field before calling `PasswordSignInAsync`.

We can't figure a way to stop a token being issued for any mobile devices using the sister application (written in Flutter) that calls the built in ID Server 4 endpoint `/connect/token`. Likewise, we can't stop the application from requesting, and then receiving, a valid refresh token. We can't hard delete the user as we have hard links to other tables in the database for auditing purposes.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

We're using DotNET Core 3,1.

EDIT: We're using the password grant type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the password grant with the built in `/connect/token` endpoint, you implement the interface `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` and add it as a Transient to the service collection. This has one method, `ValidateAsync`, and if the user referenced by your request is valid you simply `return` and the pipeline continues as normal. If your user is not valid you set the `Result.IsError` property on `CustomTokenRequestValidationContext` to true, and supply a string to `Result.Error` before you return so the token is then not issued.

Inject `UserManager<T>` and `IHttpContextAccessor` so you can access the username and user store from the method.

Here's an implementation:

```
    public class CustomTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private const string errorMessage = "invalid_username_or_password";
        public CustomTokenRequestValidator(
              UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
            , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public async Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.TryGetValue("username", out var userOut);
            var u = userOut.ToString();

            if(u != null)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(u);
                if(user == null || !user.Active)
                {
                    context.Result.IsError = true;
                    context.Result.Error = errorMessage;
                }
            } else
            {
                context.Result.IsError = true;
                context.Result.Error = errorMessage;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the client asks for a new access token using the refresh token, then the RefreshTokenService is involved. by Customizing refresh token behavior you can lookup if the user is disabled and then reject thew new access token from being issued. See this [page](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html#customizing-refresh-token-behavior) for more details about how to do this.

Alternatively you can in the class that implements IPersistedGrantStore add some code to lookup if the user is disabled and then return

```
return Task.FromResult<PersistedGrant>(null!);
```

When blocked.

Comment: Okay, I've had a look at the code and Persisted Grant never gets called because we use the password flow. Any idea what to implement for that?

Comment: Sorry, not used the password flow, but iguess you should look at the class implementing the IClientStore interface.

Comment: Forgot to come back and check my own answer as the correct one. I found out that you have to implement the ICustomTokenRequestValidator as a transient.

Comment: Great answer you made!